# IE sometimes making HEAD request with empty body instead of POST

Tags: internet-explorer, http, iis

We have a strange situation with our web application. We have several pages with HTML-forms on them. When the user presses a button the form is submitted. Sometimes this is done with Javascript like `document.forms.myform.submit()`, some other forms are submitted with the help of jQuery:

```
$.post($("form[name=myform]")[0].action,
       $("[name=myform]").serialize(), 
       fnCallback, 
       "json");
```

This will work fine 999 times a day. It results in a POST-request to our IIS webserver.
However once in a 1000 times Internet Explorer first sends a HEAD-request for the same page with an empty body. This leads to an error situation on our webserver (because it expects data in the body).
A second later the expected POST is sent correctly and life goes on.

I am aware that sometimes a HEAD request is sent just before a **GET** request and as a GET is not supposed to have a body this should work fine. In this case a HEAD is sent before a **POST**.

It happens infrequently but so far I have only seen (browseragent) this behavior with IE9/IE10/IE11 and never with IE8. This may be coincidence however.

Notes:

- The website is hosted on the Internet so (integrated) authentication does not come into play.
- All communication is strictly over https
- The forms are not particularly large, there is perhaps 100 bytes to be submitted.
- The data to be submitted is just plain text (or json), Excel is not involved in any way
- Everything is on the same domain, there is no cross-domain involved.

Comment: _"because it expects data in the body"_ - it shouldn't do that for a HEAD request.

Comment: @CodeCaster : I know that a HEAD does not send a body and I should only return the headers. But how could I ever know what headers to return when the request is incomplete (no body)? Perhaps the content-Type header depends on the post-data?